# Converting angular-dragdrop to work with firebase $asArray

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, firebase, angularfire

Pretty new to AngularJS and Firebase here, I am trying to convert angular-dragdrop.js as per the following link below to work with angularFire 0.8.0 $asArray feature:

https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/blob/master/src/angular-dragdrop.js

I was just wondering if the following changes would be sufficient:

1) Include firebase within function declaration

```
(function (window, angular, firebase, undefined) {
```

2) Include $firebase within jqyoui callback function

```
var jqyoui = angular.module('ngDragDrop', []).service('ngDragDropService', ['$firebase', '$timeout', '$parse', function($timeout, $parse) {
```

3) Change all the "push" and "splice" update on the dropModelValue and dropModelValue to $add and $remove instead.

```
dropModelValue.$add(dragItem);
```

4) Add $save after dropModelValue and dropModelValue assignments

```
dragModelValue[dragSettings.index] = dropItem;
dragModelValue[dragSettings.index].$save(dragSettings.index);
```

Your help is much appreciated. Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize [$extendFactory](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-extending-factories) to override the push/splice behaviors instead of hacking on the drag drop lib. Ideally, you would just update the priority on the records and let the server move them.

Keep in mind that Firebase data is a JSON object (not an array and therefore not ordered in JavaScript), so moving items in the array has no effect on their position on the server. You must [use priorities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data) if you want to enforce an order on the data, other than lexicographical sorting by keys.

Also, you aren't using $save correctly--you call array.$save(item), not item.$save(itemIndex).  Judging by these misconceptions, there are likely to be lots of other issues. A trip through the [Angular Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/) and the [Firebase JS Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/) be a great primer here.

Answer (score 1):

One technique I have used to reorder a Firebase array using drap & drop, is to rebind the keys to the values so that their lexicographical order match the new order set by the user. Since Firebase will enforce lexicographical order of keys, swapping the keys of 2 values will swap the values. Every time the user drops an item, rebind the keys:

```
_(myFirebaseArray)
    .map('$id')
    .sortBy() 
    // at this stage we have the array of keys sorted lexicographically
    // we pair each key with the values, which are sorted by the user
    .zipObject(myFirebaseArray) 
    // for each pair, bind the key to the value and save
    .each(function (value, newKey) {
        value.$id = newKey
        myFirebaseArray.$save(value)
    })
```

This is probably sub-optimal. I was not aware of priorities. This technique can probably be adapted fairly easily to use priorities. The code above should be compatible with [lodash](https://lodash.com) from 2 to 4.

Example of this technique in an application [here](https://github.com/hgwood/names/blob/gh-pages/app.js#L71). The `ranking` array is [bound](https://github.com/hgwood/names/blob/gh-pages/names.html#L41) to the drap & dropping through [Angular UI.Sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable).